# Editing Excel cells with a different format while keeping the current format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Say I have cells in Excel with text in it in subscript format. When I want to add more text in the cells, it will appear in subscript format. To make them appear in normal format, I have to start editing the cell, than open up the Format Cells window, than uncheck the subscript check box and than type in my text. But repeating this step for every cell I have to edit is not practical. So my question is, is there any way to prompt Excel that "For the chosen cells, do not change the current format but change the format that I will do next."?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few years back. As far as I can figure out, there's no way to do exactly what you're asking - that is, to tell Excel to always use particular formatting for added text, and ignore the formatting of existing text.

However, you can use keyboard shortcuts to make the process quicker. Specifically:

- Edit the cell (<kbd>F2</kbd>).
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type the text